# Remove all classes which contain following style

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

how do I remove all classes which contain the following style?

**HTML**

```
<div class="viewed" style="background:#F9F0D5">
   <div class="left">
        <span class="title">My </span>
            <p>MPA </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span>5</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**code sample**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('viewed')[0].style.background:#F9F0D5)[0].remove();
```

Comment: its not clear what you are asking. Could you add a before and after HTML please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript solution **[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oL24k2Lt/9/)** :

```
var viewed = document.querySelectorAll('.viewed[style="background:#F9F0D5"]');

for(i=0;i<viewed.length;i++){
    viewed[i].classList.remove('viewed');
}
```

---

You have tagged jQuery, so using jQuery selectors,

```
$('.viewed[style="background:#F9F0D5"]').removeClass('viewed');
```

To remove the element,

```
$('.viewed[style="background:#F9F0D5"]').remove();
```

Comment: It'd be nice to include the pure JS answer if possible because the post makes no *explicit* mention of jQuery. The tags aren't always right :^)

Comment: how do i remove a class if it contain following string:- +11 Points

Comment: `$('.viewed:contains("+11 Points")').removeClass('viewed');` - use contains

Comment: hey Shaunak D :- possible to trigger click on this style :-- 
`<div style="font-size:11px;color:#444;padding:2px;height:70px;">THE NEXT</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Hi refere this  https://plnkr.co/edit/FxemUZMAmEqo2oXvvMXN?p=preview

```
$(".viewed[style='background:#F9F0D5']").remove();
```

this is the syntax

```
$('div[style*=block]').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look attached snippet.

```js
$(".viewed").each(function() {
  var finalres=$(this).attr('style');
   $(this).removeClass('viewed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewed" style="background:#F9F0D5">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="title">My </span>
    <p>MPA</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="viewed" style="background:#F9F0D6">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="title">My </span>
    <p>MPA</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for?

```
$("*[style*='backlground:#F9F0D5']").removeClass()
```

Initial * can be replaced by specific selector.
but if you want to remove all the classes for the element containing the style the use or else for your example 2 options are there
1)

`$("div[style*='backlground:#F9F0D5']").removeClass()`

2)

`$(".viewed[style*='backlground:#F9F0D5']").removeClass()`

I hope this helps you